# Java Regex Problem

Tags: java, regex

I have as input text a big html file from where I have to extract some information using
pattern matching.
The "region" is somehow as follows:

```
 some html text
 <div debugState" style="display: none;">
            Model: ModelCode[BR324]
            Features: [S08TL, S0230, S0851, S0428, S01CD, S0879, S01CA, S08SP, S0698, S01CB, S0548, S08SC, S08TM, S01CC, S0801, S0258, P0668, S04AK]
            Packages: [S0801]
 </div>
        some html text
```

I wrote the following code. (At `debInfo`) is the html source to be scanned. Due to

```
Pattern model = Pattern.compile(".*(Model: ModelCode\\[\\w\\]).*, Pattern.DOTALL");
Pattern features = Pattern.compile(".*(Features: \\[\\w*\\]).*, Pattern.DOTALL");
Pattern packages = Pattern.compile(".*(Packages: \\[\\w*\\]).*, Pattern.DOTALL");


Matcher m1 = model.matcher(debInfo);
Matcher m2 = features.matcher(debInfo);
Matcher m3 = packages.matcher(debInfo);

boolean a = m1.matches();
boolean b = m2.matches();
boolean c = m3.matches();

System.out.println("matches(); " + a + " " + b + " " + c + " " + "\n" + debInfo);
```

and I am getting no match :-(.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance (a lot!)

Comment: Be aware that unless your HTML is in strict 7-bit ASCII, Java’s character class escapes will not work.  That’s because they fail to meet requirement RL1.2a from [UTS#18 Unicode Regular Expressions](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Compatibility_Properties). It also fails to meet most of the other requirements for [Basic Unicode Support](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Basic_Unicode_Support).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was missing the `MULTILINE` switch.

```
 Pattern modelPattern = Pattern.compile(".*(Model: ModelCode\\[\\w*\\]).*", Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

Comment: No, the MULTILINE flag changes the meaning of the anchors, `^` and `$`.  You aren't using anchors in that regex, so MULTILINE has no effect.

Answer (score 3):

You use `\\w` inside your (correctly escaped) square brackets. That matches only a single character. Try `\\w+` or `\\w*` instead.

Also, you have included `, Pattern.DOTALL` in your String literal, which I think is a typo:

```
Pattern model = Pattern.compile(".*(Model: ModelCode\\[\\w+\\]).*", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Also note that for the comma-and-space separated list of `Features` `\\w*` will not work, you'll need something like `[\\w\\s,]*`.

Comment: true, the "," was missing. It was a copy/paste problem, but that was not the problem. It was the MULTILINE switch what was missing.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use:

```
Pattern model = Pattern.compile(".*(Model: ModelCode\\[\\w*\\]).*", Pattern.DOTALL);
Pattern features = Pattern.compile(".*(Features: \\[\\w*\\]).*", Pattern.DOTALL);
Pattern packages = Pattern.compile(".*(Packages: \\[\\w*\\]).*", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Comment: The `*` is missing in the first pattern.

Comment: @Luixv: then your sample HTML is wrong, as it's got multiple characters at that point.

Answer (score 1):

These are the correct patterns:

```
Pattern modelPattern = Pattern.compile(".*Model: ModelCode\\[(\\w*)\\].*",
        Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE);
Pattern featuresPattern = Pattern.compile(".*Features: \\[([\\w\\s,]*)\\].*",
        Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE);
Pattern packagesPattern = Pattern.compile(".*Packages: \\[([\\w\\s,]*)\\].*",
        Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE);
```